# Python - Stacking 3D images (stored as arrays) to create a 4D array

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

All,

I have 25,000 RGB images that am trying to stack in python to create a 4D array. Each of my 25k images is a 150x150x3 array (with dtype=uint16). And I want to create a 4D array of size [25000, 150, 150, 3]. Here’s the pseudo-code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
myfourdarray = np.empty[25000,150, 150, 3]
for idx in range(25000):
    img = read from file which returns a 150x150x3
    myfourdarray[idx] = img
```

The above code has been running for 8 hours and is still going. idx is now up to 12000 and code is still going. It is really slow. I replaced the file reading part of the code with images generated using random numbers and the code behaved the same - slow and kept chugging along for hours. Can someone please help me figure out what I did wrong? Is there a better and faster way to stack 3D arrays and create a 4D array?

Thanks 
P. S. Am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747021/create-numpy-array-of-images

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

myfourdarray = []

for idx in range(25000):

    img = read from file which returns a 150x150x3

    myfourdarray.append(img)

out = np.stack(myfourdarray, axis = 0)
```

could be faster, but I didn't validate it.